# Running a script after a certain amount of time of inactivity

Tags: scripts

I am fairly new to script writing and cannot find how to do what I am trying to do. 
I am trying to have a script ask for user input confirmation in a pop up on screen for convenience. Lets say it does this every 24 hours. If input is not given, it displays a text file (preferably like a .doc file) and terminates leaving the file open. if input is given, it resets for another 24 hours. The user input does not have to be complicated, it is simply for human confirmation to reset.

I hope there is something out there that can do this. Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Comment: There needs to be some clarification here.  How do you want to obtain user's input ? Via command-line ? Via a pop-up dialog ? Where and how the text should be displayed ?  It's quite possible to write what you ask, just needs to be clarified

Comment: I  imagine a pop-up would be most convenient but ultimately have no preference as long as it works. I will edit post to include clarification.

Comment: Hey, Nikki, I posted a quick sketch script of what you've requested, let me know if any part of it needs to be edited or improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small script that will display a popup every 24 hours, as you've requested ( the `sleep 24h` part). When launching the script you must provide two command-line arguments - the time to wait for user input from popup and full-path (!) to the file you want to open. Example:

```
./dialog_timeout.sh 3 /etc/passwd
```

Since you mentioned this is just for human verification, the script only checks if what was returned by the input dialog is non-empty ( because the input dialog gets killed by `timeout` command after timeout is reached,so the input will be empty). So in other words, you **must** type something in. Note that if you click cancel or if you click OK but your input was empty, then the script will assume fail condition, so it will display the document you want.

Note: standard rules for making scripts workable apply - store file preferably in `~/bin` and ensure it is executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/dialog_timeout.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
got_input()
{
    result=$(timeout $1 zenity --entry --text "Type something")
    if [ "x$result" != "x" ]
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

main()
{
    while true
    do
        if got_input "$1"
        then 
            sleep 24h
        else
            xdg-open "$2"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: that is what I wanted! thank you so much.  The only thing is the window for user input is very small, When testing with a short sleep time, I barely had time to type anything. is there a way of giving a bit more of a window for input?

Comment: @NikkiFraser well, there sort of is a way to make window itself larger, but the input field won't change, so it's kind of pointless.  `zenity --entry --text "Type something" --width 250 --height 250` will make the window 250 by 250 pixels, for example; it is also possible if you go into custom GUI programming instead of using `zenity` but that's quite a lot of work for something simple.  I would suggest you increase the time given on command line, so `./dialog_timeout.sh 10 /etc/passwd` would wait for 10 seconds, so you'll have more time to type.

Comment: Thank you.  I had meant the window of time for input not window size. By time I realized my mistake, you had already answered.  Thank you so much for all the help. This is perfect for the purpose.